# Implementing ReactJS into Angular App

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a website and tried to include a ReactJS component and I'm doing it like so:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Layout from "Layout.jsx";

const app = angular.module('myApp');

const reactDirective = app.directive('reactDirective', function() {

  return {
      template: '<div id="reactapp"></div>',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs){
          ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, document.getElementById('reactapp'));
        }
    }
});
```

and the Layout.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                This is ReactJS
            </div>
        );
   }
}
```

However whenever it compiles, it gives me
`ERROR in ./react-app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'layout.jsx'`
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports of local files that don't live in `node_modules` have to be relative paths.

```
import Layout from "./Layout.jsx";
```